# grep date and time from txt file for new variables

Tags: linux, sed, grep, date, variable

I need to extract dates (year,month,day) and times (hour,minutes) from a text file and use them later as variables. Not a homework, just trying to do something useful for my work. I am new to Linux.

INPUT: The text file contains list of files named like:

```
S3G_MX_1_EFR____20100203T121015_othernumbers.zip
```

Desired output is:

```
2010 02 03 12 10
```

I'd like to put them separately into few variables: year, month, day, hour, minutes. 
Should I use grep? Or sed? Or awk? Did a lot of reading, but feel stressed by amount of possibilities. Is it possible to write expression like "4 numbers after the string  `S3G_MX_1_EFR____` is "year"? I don't need complete code, just need a bit of advice what options/commands to use or where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep and bash:

```bsh
filename="S3G_MX_1_EFR____20100203T121015_othernumbers.zip"
timestamp=$( echo "$filename" | grep -oP '(?<=\D)\d{8}T\d{4}' )
```

then

```bsh
year=${timestamp:0:4};    echo $year      # => 2010
month=${timestamp:4:2};   echo $month     # => 02
day=${timestamp:6:2};     echo $day       # => 03
hour=${timestamp:9:2};    echo $hour      # => 12
minute=${timestamp:11:2}; echo $minute    # => 10
```

Actually, plain bash will do (need version 4+)

```bsh
regex='_([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})'
if [[ $filename =~ $regex ]]; then
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    hour=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    minute=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
    echo "$year $month $day $hour $minute"
fi
```

```bsh
2010 02 03 12 10
```

Comment: Thank you! I loved the plain bash solution. Worked perfectly. But I had a problem with adding 3 extra  columns for /other numbers (end date and time). like this:  {regex='_([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{8})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})'} The file name is S3G_MX_1_EFR____20100203T121015_20100203T1315 - am I doing smth wrong? I also added  {endate=${BASH_REMATCH[6]}
hh=${BASH_REMATCH[7]}
mm=${BASH_REMATCH[8]}} Actually I need only the second time(dont need enddate, but dont get any output of script as soon as I add this.

Comment: There are 6 digits after the "T"

Comment: Thank you! My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do a replacement like

```
sed -E 's/.*S3G_MX_1_EFR____(....)(..)(..)T(..)(..).*/export year=\1 month=\2 day=\3 hour=\4 minute=\5/'
```

Those patterns like `(....)` (extended regular expression syntax) match the four digits after the pattern and can be used in the replacement as `\1` and following. So the result for your example will be

```
export year=2010 month=02 day=03 hour=12 minute=10
```

This lines can be executed, e.g.

```
$(echo S3G_MX_1_EFR____20100203T121015_othernumbers.zip | sed -E 's/.*S3G_MX_1_EFR____(....)(..)(..)T(..)(..).*/export year=\1 month=\2 day=\3 hour=\4 minute=\5/')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!